# How to convert XML type return text into select columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the column names of a table using `XML` datatype and `information_schema` columns. When I tried to use the result in another select statement, I have the results with the repeated column name instead of the results set. I have even tried to cast it to `varchar` but it still failed. what have done wrong ?

```
DECLARE @TSQL1 varchar(1000);

SELECT @TSQL1 = CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
                      FROM [ProdLS].[ information_schema.columns] 
                      WHERE table_name = 'roles' 
                      ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION 
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 200000)) AS varchar(max));

 SELECT @TSQL1 
 FROM [aubeakon_scrm4].[acl_roles]
```

My query to get the results from roles table using the column name retrieved from.

Comment: Sorry couldn't add my last command 
 select @TSQL1 from [aubeakon_scrm4].[acl_roles] 
Results: It just returned the column names for each row instead of the data

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't put it in the comments, @Richard .

Comment: Would you send a sample of columns and data in your table?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute dynamic SQL like that. You need to use `sp_executesql`. You also need to declare dynamic SQL as `nvarchar(max)`.

> You should also use `.value` to unescape the XML

```sql
DECLARE @TSQL1 nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT 
' + STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
    FROM [ProdLS].[information_schema].columns
    WHERE table_name = 'roles' 
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(', '), '') + '
FROM [aubeakon_scrm4].[acl_roles];
';

EXEC sp_executesql @TSQL1;
```